# Need help in making a Model for Json file in iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, model

I have this API "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-07&end_date=2015-09-08&api_key=DEMO_KEY"

The Model I have created is -

```
struct NearEarthObjects: Codable {
    let near_earth_objects: [CloseApproachData]
}

struct CloseApproachData: Codable {
    let relative_velocity: [RelativeVelocity]
}

struct RelativeVelocity: Codable {
    let kilometers_per_hour: String
}
```

I am not able to get the data by using this model in my program. Need help parsing it correctly.

Using below line of code in Service file

```
let neoResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(NearEarthObjects.self, from: data)
                    print(neoResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

as Per https://app.quicktype.io/ your codable structure will look like below.

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Response
struct Response: Codable {
    let links: ResponseLinks
    let elementCount: Int
    let nearEarthObjects: [String: [NearEarthObject]]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case links
        case elementCount = "element_count"
        case nearEarthObjects = "near_earth_objects"
    }
}

// MARK: - ResponseLinks
struct ResponseLinks: Codable {
    let next, prev, linksSelf: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case next, prev
        case linksSelf = "self"
    }
}

// MARK: - NearEarthObject
struct NearEarthObject: Codable {
    let links: NearEarthObjectLinks
    let id, neoReferenceID, name: String
    let nasaJplURL: String
    let absoluteMagnitudeH: Double
    let estimatedDiameter: EstimatedDiameter
    let isPotentiallyHazardousAsteroid: Bool
    let closeApproachData: [CloseApproachDatum]
    let isSentryObject: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case links, id
        case neoReferenceID = "neo_reference_id"
        case name
        case nasaJplURL = "nasa_jpl_url"
        case absoluteMagnitudeH = "absolute_magnitude_h"
        case estimatedDiameter = "estimated_diameter"
        case isPotentiallyHazardousAsteroid = "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid"
        case closeApproachData = "close_approach_data"
        case isSentryObject = "is_sentry_object"
    }
}

// MARK: - CloseApproachDatum
struct CloseApproachDatum: Codable {
    let closeApproachDate, closeApproachDateFull: String
    let epochDateCloseApproach: Int
    let relativeVelocity: RelativeVelocity
    let missDistance: MissDistance
    let orbitingBody: OrbitingBody

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case closeApproachDate = "close_approach_date"
        case closeApproachDateFull = "close_approach_date_full"
        case epochDateCloseApproach = "epoch_date_close_approach"
        case relativeVelocity = "relative_velocity"
        case missDistance = "miss_distance"
        case orbitingBody = "orbiting_body"
    }
}

// MARK: - MissDistance
struct MissDistance: Codable {
    let astronomical, lunar, kilometers, miles: String
}

enum OrbitingBody: String, Codable {
    case earth = "Earth"
}

// MARK: - RelativeVelocity
struct RelativeVelocity: Codable {
    let kilometersPerSecond, kilometersPerHour, milesPerHour: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case kilometersPerSecond = "kilometers_per_second"
        case kilometersPerHour = "kilometers_per_hour"
        case milesPerHour = "miles_per_hour"
    }
}

// MARK: - EstimatedDiameter
struct EstimatedDiameter: Codable {
    let kilometers, meters, miles, feet: Feet
}

// MARK: - Feet
struct Feet: Codable {
    let estimatedDiameterMin, estimatedDiameterMax: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case estimatedDiameterMin = "estimated_diameter_min"
        case estimatedDiameterMax = "estimated_diameter_max"
    }
}

// MARK: - NearEarthObjectLinks
struct NearEarthObjectLinks: Codable {
    let linksSelf: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case linksSelf = "self"
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
do {
   let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
}catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Comment: Don’t use `try?` when decoding downloaded (external) json.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson is there any problem with `try?`?

Comment: You are ignoring any possible decoding errors

Comment: @JoakimDanielson so i need to go with `do-try-catch` block. Right?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson okay thanks for the information :) i will update my answer

Comment: I did some adjustments, note that by not using localizedDescription when printing the error you will get a more detailed and informative error message

Comment: How do I use the result values. Like if I want to show the id as a label in my View Controller how to i use it from the results. @jatinfl

Comment: Your question has been answered, please do not ask more question in the comments. You need to post a new question instead

Comment: @jatinfl Please let me know , your help is much appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: @Sanchita id is codable object of nearEarthObjects. and nearEarthObjects is kind of array so you can retrive it like loop on array eg. `for element in response.nearEarthObjects { print(element.id) }`

Comment: @jatinfl Okay , I'll try it out . Thank you so much !